# WordPress DevOps – Environments (Rancher, Kubernetes, etc...)

Tags: plugins, docker

in my company we are trying to use WordPress on Docker. Our target is to give a “staging” envrionment where users/editors can make changes, update plugins/themes, write pages/articles, etc….

We want to make a “snapshot” of the version on the staging and deploy it to the production environment, where we want to disable the wp-admin area (security reasons).

This might me doable but we are facing a problem related to the plugin management. On staging and production the database can be quite different and we all know that WP saves absolute paths so we also have to do a replacement for the domain.

The issue is that the settings of the plugins might reside in different tables as not every plugin saves stuff in wp_option. So the problem is to understand how to pick only the changes made to plugins on staging and deploy to production without taking all the DB.

Is there any experience on this scenario available in the community?
Has anybody tried to have multiple environments with Worpdress on Docker?
We are using Rancher for the orchestration.

Comment: you have some things very wrong. Staging enviroment should be an exact duplicate of production enviroment. This is probably the only thing for which there is a point to use docker.

Comment: I guess the core of why you are having trouble is "we want to disable the wp-admin area (security reasons)." This is not security, it is a security theater, which make your life harder while improving your security in a very marginal way, if any at all.

Comment: That sounds ok. The main point beside cutting out the admin area in prod (which might not give us the desired peace of mind) is to have an automatic deployment pipeline.

For example, if in staging we have updated some settings for a plugin(s) then how we deploy only that part of the DB in prod? 

Themes might not be a problem since we do not have settings for it in the DB.

Comment: but this is the idea behind docker AFAIK. The image is independent of the host and you can just duplicate it from one enviroment to another. This will solve you DB related issues (but this requires staging and production to have n exact same enviroment). Outside of docker the rule of thumb is that DB changes never propagate from staging to production. If you need to control some option, just filter the value of the relevant options in your code